# angle between two point coordinates to rotate image accordingly

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, cgaffinetransform

I have two points of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, let's say A & B on my `mapView`. I would like an arrow-image to point from one point to another (A->B). I am unable to find the right angle to `transform` arrow-image.

Please see this image for reference [image: example screen-shot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WT u have to tried ??

Comment: I feel like this is geometry 101, here.  Have you tried doing a little math (trig to be exact)?  Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586063/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-two-points-relative-to-the-horizontal-axis

Comment: thanks for the response, I have 
`float deltaLongitude = second.longitude - first.longitude;float deltaLatitude = second.latitude - first.latitude;float angle = atan2(deltaLongitude, deltaLatitude) * 180 / M_PI;pointerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);`
but rotation of image is still not good.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but perhaps it could still help someone looking here:

```
CGFloat angle = atan2f(point2.y - point1.y, point2.x - point1.x);
CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
arrow.transform = rotationTransform;
```

If you want to place a `UIImageView` "arrow" at point 1, and have it point to point 2, you just use the deltas to get an arctangent, then create a transform based on that angle, and assign that transform to the `UIImageView` of the arrow.