# Animating an object along coordinates with window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to get an object (a bus) to animate along a predetermined path on the scroll event.

The idea is to have it working in a similar fashion to [this site](http://rit-team.ru/). Unfortunately the original work is difficult to reverse engineer, despite being unminified, as a lot of the variable names are only 1-2 characters long and I am no mathematician.

I have a *very* rough draught available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UzD9z/1/) though as you will see there is something wrong with my rotation calculations taken from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586063/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-two-points-relative-to-the-horizontal-axis). Also the bus doesn't move back to the correct starting position.

```
        // Work out the angle to rotate the bus to for the next point.
        // MATHS!! 
        var deltaY = toTop - top,
            deltaX = toLeft - left,
            angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

I know the waypoints are off just now.

Cheers.

Comment: Something like GSAP might be helpful: http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/ when paired with the Bezier path plugin: http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/plugins/BezierPlugin.html

Comment: Cheers, I'll check it out.