# Get Marker Location From Current Location Android Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building an app for android. I have a marker and a circle around that marker with a radius.

When the current location intersects the radius of the circle then a warning message is displayed.

I would like to be able to tell with the alert message that the center of the circle which equals to the marker location is in the east, west, north or south depending in the current location.

I would appreciate your help on how to achieve that. and I hope that my request is clear.

Many Thanks,

Abdullah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no one has not yet given any answer, I will try and come up with a suggestion.

I believe you could simplify the matter by thinking of the the two points as 2-dimensional points in the euclidian space (assuming that the radius around the marker is not very large).

Given the two points, lets call them `x={xlat,ylng}` and `y={ylat,ylng}`, x being the current location and y being the marker.

Now calculate delta_lat and delta_lng.

```
delta_lat=xlat-ylat
delta_lng=xlng-ylng
```

And calculate the angle between the two points using the delta values

```
angleInDegrees = atan2(delta_lat, delta_lng) * 180 / PI
```

Angle calulation found from: [How to calculate the angle between a line and the horizontal axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586063/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-two-points-relative-to-the-horizontal-axis)

Now, having the degree it should be trivial to determine whether the direction is east, west, north or south.