# Move along spiral to the centre with cartasian coordinates given at the start

Tags: java, processing, polar-coordinates, spiral

I would like to move the ellipse along the spiral to the centre of the screen - the starting point of the ellipse is given via x and y coordinates. Well I have no idea how to push the spiral inward the centre (I can achieve this by adding width/2 and height/2 to the x,y) AND AT THE SAME TIME start the movement at the given cartasian (x,y) coordinates. Below is the code. Help appreciated!
I have been trying to do this in processing (java):

```
float r = 0; //radius
float x = 700; // x of the object
float y = 50; // y of the object
float theta = 0; //angle

void setup() {
  size(800,600);
  background(0);
  smooth();

  r = sqrt(x*x+y*y); //polar coordinate - distance from x,y to 0,0 on the grid
  theta = atan(y/x); // angle to 0,0 on the grid

}

void draw() {

  fill(0,255,0);
  rect(width/2,height/2,20,20);

  fill(0,0,255);
  rect(700,50,20,20);

  float x = r * cos(theta);
  float y = r * sin(theta);

  // Draw an ellipse at x,y
  noStroke();
  fill(255,0,0);

  ellipse(x, y, 16, 16); 

  if (r>0){
  r -= 1; // Increment the radius
  theta += 0.01; // Increment the angle
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could translate your x,y and then translate the draw loop.

This makes it so that you're working with a coordinate system with 0,0 at the center of the screen instead of at the top-left of the screen.

Your distance and angle formulas are using 0,0 as the origin, which is not the center of the screen if you use a top-left origin system (like Processing). You could also modify those formulas instead.

The below code is an edit of yours to make 0,0 at the center of your screen.

```
float r = 0; //radius
float x = 100; // x of the object
float y = 100; // y of the object
float theta = 0; //angle

void setup() {
  size(800,600);
  background(0);
  smooth();
  ellipseMode(CENTER); // draw ellipses based on their center

  // translate the x and y from top-left origin to center origin 
  x -= width/2;
  y -= height/2;

  r = sqrt(x*x+y*y); //polar coordinate - distance from x,y to 0,0 on the grid
  theta = atan(y/x); // angle to 0,0 on the grid

}

void draw() {
  translate(width/2, height/2); // translate the whole canvas

  fill(0,255,0);
  ellipse(0,0,20,20); // mark the center of the canvas

  fill(0,0,255);
  ellipse(x,y,20,20); // mark the start point for the circle

  // flip the angle if left of the origin
  int flip = 1;
  if(x < 0) flip = -1;

  float x = r * cos(theta) * flip;
  float y = r * sin(theta) * flip;

  // Draw an ellipse at x,y
  noStroke();
  fill(255,0,0);

  ellipse(x, y, 16, 16); 

  if (r>0){
  r -= 1; // Decrement the radius
  theta += 0.01; // Increment the angle
  }

}
```

The below code keeps the top-left origin, but modifies the initialization of the radius and angle to be relative to the center of the screen.

```
float x = 100; // x of the object
float y = 100; // y of the object
float r = 0; // radius
float theta = 0; // angle

void setup() {
  size(800,600);
  background(0);
  smooth();
  ellipseMode(CENTER); // draw ellipses based on their center

  // distance between point and center of screen
  r = dist(x,y,width/2,height/2);

  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/7586218/1736092
  // angle of line between point and center of screen 
  // relative to x-axis
  float dX = x - width/2;
  float dY = y - height/2; 
  theta = atan2(dY, dX);

  stroke(0, 255, 0); // green stroke
  line(x, y, width/2, height/2); // draw radius

  noStroke();
  fill(0, 255, 0);  // green fill
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, 20, 20); // mark the center of the canvas
  fill(0, 0, 255); // blue fill
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20); // mark the start point for the circle
}

void draw() {
  float x = r * cos(theta) + width/2;
  float y = r * sin(theta) + height/2;

  noStroke();
  fill(255,0,0); // red fill
  ellipse(x, y, 16, 16); 

  if(r>0) {
    r -= 1; // Decrement the radius
    theta += 0.01; // Increment the angle
  }
}
```

Comment: Just trying to run the suggested code and it seems that its a mess when changing the starting point - lets say to x=100, y=100 the marking point has different position. It may be working when checking for quadrants - I will try to test that.

Comment: OK So what I had to do was to add condition when drawing ellipse to check if the first given x was larger than half of the canvas. Still wondering why I can not use x to check it and have to set second global i like float i = x;....CODE:                                                       if (i<width/2){ // have to check against global variable that is declared as x...dunno why?
  ellipse(-x, -y, 16, 16);  
  }else{
  ellipse(x, y, 16, 16); 
  }

Comment: Updated to fix this bug. I forgot that if you are left (negative) of the origin, the angle method you are using will flip the angle. The update demonstrates a way to check for this and flip at the appropriate point in the code without needing to set a global.

Comment: Added code to show a better method of modifying the initial radius and angle to be relative to the center of the screen without moving the origin from the top-left.