# Calculating angle between two points - java

Tags: java, lines, angle, points

I need to calculate the angle in degrees between two points, with a fixed point that is connected with the given two points by a line.

Here is an image that illustrates what I need:

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
public static float GetAngleOfLineBetweenTwoPoints(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2) {
        float xDiff = x2 - x1;
        float yDiff = y2 - y1;
        return (float) (Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * (180 / Math.PI));
}
```

It's pointless to say that it doesn't provide the correct answer.

Comment: You do not even consider the coordinates of the "origin" point currently, right?

Comment: what is your fixed point?you also need that point

Comment: add third point (as @getlost mentioned) and use vector angle formula: http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/vec/angle_vectors.html

Comment: From @RomeoKienzler post (because it's not an answer), you should review this: [How to calculate the angle between a line and the horizontal axis?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7586063/1065197)

Answer (score 18):

You can have the following method that calculates the angle in radians using the `Math.atan2` method:

```
public static double angleBetweenTwoPointsWithFixedPoint(double point1X, double point1Y, 
        double point2X, double point2Y, 
        double fixedX, double fixedY) {

    double angle1 = Math.atan2(point1Y - fixedY, point1X - fixedX);
    double angle2 = Math.atan2(point2Y - fixedY, point2X - fixedX);

    return angle1 - angle2; 
}
```

And call it with three points (using `Math.toDregrees` to transform resulting angle from radians to degrees):

```
System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(
            angleBetweenTwoPointsWithFixedPoint(0, 0, // point 1's x and y
                                                1, 1, // point 2
                                                1, 0  // fixed point
                                               )));
```

Output: 90.0

Feel free to use Java's standard `Point` or `Line2D` classes in your solution though. This was just to demonstrate it works.

Comment: To make this work properly I had to add a correction of the result (after converting it to degrees):
      `if (result < 0)
            result += 360;`
Otherwise my result was switching between ~270 and ~90 degrees (with a fixed point in the bottom right corner).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a code snippet from my Android Gesture library. It works and is fully tested.

```
public double getAngleFromPoint(Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint) {

    if((secondPoint.x > firstPoint.x)) {//above 0 to 180 degrees

        return (Math.atan2((secondPoint.x - firstPoint.x), (firstPoint.y - secondPoint.y)) * 180 / Math.PI);

    }
    else if((secondPoint.x < firstPoint.x)) {//above 180 degrees to 360/0

        return 360 - (Math.atan2((firstPoint.x - secondPoint.x), (firstPoint.y - secondPoint.y)) * 180 / Math.PI);

    }//End if((secondPoint.x > firstPoint.x) && (secondPoint.y <= firstPoint.y))

    return Math.atan2(0 ,0);

}//End public float getAngleFromPoint(Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint)
```

Comment: man, this is actually the only valid answer I found in Stack Overflow. All others are not working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can i get the value of `x`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know @user2288580 but even for simple, test-cases your code is failing.

firstPoint = (0,0)
secondPoint = (0, 5), (5,5), (5,0), (5, -5) (0, -5) (-5, -5), (-5, 0)

Please see if this works for you @David -

```
public double angleBetween2CartesianPoints(double firstX, double firstY, double secondX, double secondY) {
    double angle = Math.atan2((secondX - firstX), (secondY - firstY)) * 180 / Math.PI;
    if (angle < 0) {
        return (360 + angle);
    } else {
        return (angle);
    }
}
```