# Calculate the interior angle of a triangle

Tags: imageview, compass, navigator, degrees

i'm trying to create a simple navigator, with an arrow that indicate the direction from the location where i'm to the location saved in the map, like a compass with north.
i've two location (long and lat), start point and final point.
The arrow must rotate from north to the final point direction. I need to calculate this movement i degrees. 
It's like two side of a triangle, and the movement is the interior angle.

How can calculate this angle, knowing the two distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic trig:

```
deltaY = P2_y - P1_y
deltaX = P2_x - P1_x
angleInDegrees = atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * (180 / PI)
```

Via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586218/1167783).