# Fire event when reach certain angle in revolute joint

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, box2d, revolute-joints

I need to develop cannon game using **box2d** and **cocos2dx**. Cannon is divided into two parts

- **Base** which is fixed in the ground and doesn't move.

  ```
  b2WeldJointDef basePlatformWeldJointDef;
  basePlatformWeldJointDef.Initialize(base->getBody(), weaponPlatform->getBody(),weaponPlatform->getBody()->GetWorldCenter());
  basePlatformWeldJointDef.collideConnected = false;
  basePlatformWeldJoint = m_world->CreateJoint(&basePlatformWeldJointDef);
  ```
- **Arm** which is fixed in the base with a **RevoluteJoint**.

  ```
  b2RevoluteJointDef armJointDef;
  armJointDef.Initialize(base->getBody(), arm->getBody(), m_loader->pointsToMeters(ccp(armPosition.x-(arm->getContentSize().width*WeaponScale/4),armPosition.y)));

  armJointDef.enableMotor = true;
  armJointDef.enableLimit = true;
  armJointDef.motorSpeed  = 0;
  armJointDef.lowerAngle  = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0);
  armJointDef.upperAngle  = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0);
  armJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 2;

  armJointDef.collideConnected = false;

  cannonRevoluteJoint = (b2RevoluteJoint*)m_world->CreateJoint(&armJointDef);
  ```
- The cannon should calculate the angle that will fire to, and this is calculated correctly. Using the `revolutJointObject->setLimits(lowerAngle, higherAngle)` here i use the *lowerAngle* and the *higherAngle* both are the desired angle so the arm moves to desired angle directly without motion.
- Then i needed to move the arm not just change its angle, so i set the lowerAngle and higherAngle with the old angle and desired angle depending which will be the lower and the which will the higher, and changed the motor speed of the **RevoluteJoint**
- The problem is that i need a *callback* method which fires when the revolute joint reaches to a certain angle or when the motor speed reaches Zero assuming that when the arm reaches the limit angle will stop and the motor speed will be Zero.

I have searching in SO and i found [This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820172/rotation-finding-when-desired-angle-is-reached) which calculates the angle each step, this can be used but it needs more calculations that i feel lazy to do.

Does the callback method for notifying motor speed or certain angle has been reached exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule a function to check your conditions on each frame. When you don't need the checks any more - unschedule the selector, then reschedule when needed again.
As far as I know there are no callbacks for your exact task.

Comment: then i make my check in the step it is just an if condition doesn't need whole new method to be scheduled

Comment: Just don't sacrifice design to premature optimization, otherwise - whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

All a callback would do behind the scenes is check the angle each frame and then call the callback function when the joint angle is within a certain range.

There's no built in callbacks for this use case. You could make your own to hide what's going on, or you could just put the if statement in the update function. The performance of this will be fine.